# I have a checkbox that correlates directly to an input amount. If there is an input amount the checkbox has to be checked before post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've created a function for a standard checkbox in php, it's called cbox as well as a standard input box called inp.

```
<tr><td><?php cbox('charge_cc'); ?> Charge CC? Amount $ <?php inp('charge_amt'); ?></td></tr>
```

If there is an amount entered into the 'charge_amt' inp field the checkbox needs to be checked as well before they post/submit.

If no amount has been entered into the input field than they do not need to check the box and can proceed to fill out the rest of the form and submit. I'm uncertain on how to accomplish this because i think my php functions for cbox and inp are breaking my jquery/javascript.

As of now i've tried a few variations:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
if (document.getElementById('charge_cc').checked){
          alert("checked") ;
}else{
alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
}
}
</script>
```

No avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="charge_cc" value="0" class="charge_cc">
    <input type="checkbox" id="charge_cc" name="charge_cc" value="1" class="charge_cc"> Charge CC? Amount $ <input type="text" id="charge_amt" name="charge_amt" value="" size="8" maxlength="6"></td>
```

Comment: Is the checkbox really necessary?

Comment: you added some code, what exactly does your html look like for the checkbox?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as firebug?

Comment: what is the html output (view source in browser), not the php src

Comment: updated for the html output

Comment: Can the user un-check the check-box once it's been checked by the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to check/uncheck the checkbox depending on an entry in the `charge_amt` text-input, I'd suggest:

```
$('#charge_amt').keyup(function(){
    var that = this;
    $('#charge_cc').prop('checked', function(){
        return that.value.length;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p3gc2/).

If you want to prevent the user un-checking the checkbox once there's a value in the text-input:

```
$('#charge_amt').keyup(function () {
    var test = this.value.length;
    $('#charge_cc').prop({
        'checked': test,
            'disabled': test
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p3gc2/1/).

Comment: That worked beautifully and I should of knew it was that easy. I forgot my $(document).ready(function(). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery... if you have a checkbox with an id of charge_cc, this should work

```
if($("#charge_cc").prop("checked")) ...
```

jsfiddle with your html and alerts: http://jsfiddle.net/kmV9m/

Comment: how did you use it? the first will return true or false based on whether a checkbox with the ID of "charge_cc" (like you mentioned in your script above) is checked.

Comment: should i just wrap it in a div and give it an id or class?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#charge_amt').on('change', function () {
        var amount = $(this).val();
        if (amount.length > 0) {
            $('#charge_cc').prop('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            $('#charge_cc').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
})
```

Using a bit of jQuery here to do the work for you should do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/2HZFE/